# How to set userid in docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am starting some docker containers (to run a website) in a docker-compose.yaml file. I want the code for the website to be in a directory on the host, with the files owned by the user who is going to run `sudo docker-compose up -d` to start the container. This is so the user can easily read or edit them, or add new ones. The website in the docker container will also create some files, and I want them to be owned by the right user too.

So it would be good if the user **inside** the docker container which is going to run the website scripts had the same UID and GID as the user running docker-compose.

So far, I have achieved this by working out the UID and GID (using `id`), and hard coding them into the docker-compose.yaml file.

However, it would be good if I could move this docker-compose file to other machines, where the UID and GID might not be the same.

The UID is already available in the environment, and I guess GID could be put there somehow. Is there a way of setting these up and passing them into the docker container so it creates and uses a user with the same UID and GID, so the files have the right ownership and permission?

Comment: If you want a host user to run host code with their host user ID so they can edit host files, an isolation tool like Docker might not be the right setup for you.  Consider using your language's normal packaging tools (Node's `node_modules` directory, Python virtual environments, ...) to get some separation between different applications running on the host.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to me that you have an ok solution set up where you can just set the UID and GID in the compose file and you're good to go. Did you hack the entrypoint of your container to start by making a user with that UID and GID, and then to start your main service? It is more common to hardcode the UID and GID at build time, set the user to the user you want at build time, and then have the entrypoint just run your service.

(This does lead to a classic Docker conundrum when you need to use bind-mounts though, if the bind-mount between the Docker user UID/GID and the folder location's UID/GID do not match - I suspect this is what led to whatever mechanism you are using right now. I have set up file permissions on shared bind-mounts (which is how you share files between the person running the container and the container) before, using ACLs, it can be kind of a doozy but can be made correct if you are careful.) edit: David Maze just left a great comment on your original post that maybe Docker isn't even the right tool for you to set up this server. I think you should strongly consider his suggestion before you jump into stuff like mucking with ACls by hand.

Anyway if what you have now is good enough, then it's good enough, I guess. If you are really truly doing ok just editing the UID and GID in your compose file, you can pass those to the container with a stanza like this:

```
    environment:
      - UID=${UID:?err}
      - GID=${GID:?err}
```

this will pull UID and GID out of your own environment when you start running the container, and throw an error and prevent the container from starting if for some reason UID or GID are unset.